# How to communicate between docker container including localhost machine

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

My question :

```
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    container_name: zookeeper
    image: debezium/zookeeper:${DEBEZIUM_VERSION}
    ports:
     - 2181:2181
     - 2888:2888
     - 3888:3888
  kafka:
    container_name: kafka
    image: debezium/kafka:${DEBEZIUM_VERSION}
    ports:
     - 9092:9092
    links:
     - zookeeper
    environment:
     - ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181  
  connect:
    container_name: connect
    image: debezium/connect:${DEBEZIUM_VERSION}
    ports:
     - 8083:8083
    links:
     - kafka
    environment:
     - BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=kafka:9092
     - GROUP_ID=1
     - CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_configs
     - OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_offsets
     - STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_statuses
```

Here I want `connect` container to call my localhost PostGres

but it is throws cannot connect to jdbs:postgresql//localhost:5432/test error

So how can I set the networking of `connect` so that

1. It can discover `zookeeper` and `kafka`
2. It can also connent to my localhost machine

PS
I tried adding  `network_mode: host` in connect but then it did not discover the kafka and zookeeper

Comment: same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach

Answer (score 0):

localhost for `connect` is docker's private network, not your computers localhost where your postgres apparently is.

You need to use `network_mode: host`, but of course then the other 2 containers will be left unreachable on private network. So solution is to either use `network_mode: host` for all containers, OR bring your postgres to the same docker-compose file as a docker container so that it is too on the private network

Comment: Or just use a DNS hostname or IP in the connection string. That is, if Postgres is not in a container itself.

Comment: `network_mode: host` generally disables Docker networking, and I wouldn't usually recommend it.  The canonical question linked to above describes some other paths that work (particularly on MacOS or Windows hosts).